# Does the distance between light sources and detectors influence the result of beam splitting experiments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, photons

I have this experimental setup in mind:
[image: experimental setup]

Here, the paths between L (light source) and D1/D2 (detectors) have exactly the same lengths. Normally, this would give a 50% chance of photon detection at each detector.

My question is whether the path distance has to be exactly equal for the outcomes to be 50/50, or whether placing one detector further away changes the probabilities in any way.

It would seem to me that if the probabilities are the same (but with a time delay for the longer path, accounting for travel time), then the photon took a discrete path from source to detector as otherwise it would seem to potentially have to travel backwards in time in order to "decide" which detector to be received at (I know this is badly phrased, hopefully my meaning comes across).

Comment: light beams can be split, no photons. Photons are element,ary quantum mechanical particles , they interact and change direction or a different photon with less energy can leave the interaction. Light beams can be split because they are composed by zillion of photons ( in a quantum mechanical way)

Comment: @annav thanks, I clarified the question.

Comment: Is there only one beam splitter in the experiment? Because if so, then the mirrors and the distances to the detectors don't change anything.